# How do I open a site using ASP.net Core in Docker on Ubuntu on Google.Cloud?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-14.04

When I run docker with Asp.net Core locally everything is ok. But when I use the Ubuntu virtual machine in cloud.google, I kind of start the container and everything works. But I don't know how to open the site. Login via External ip doesn't open anything. I just have "Can't access the site" Although everything opens locally. Am I missing any settings?
Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj", "WebApplication1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication1"
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```

Command: sudo docker run -d -p 8000:80 gamehomm/webapplication1

Comment: Edit your question and show the commands that you are using to run the container. Include your Dockerfile and what ports your application is listening on. Most likely you have a port mapping problem (map port 80/443 -> container listening ports). The answer requires more details.

Comment: Read read my comment and edit your question with all requested details. Note: EXPOSE does nothing to expose ports.

Comment: Is your .NET application listening on port 80? Are you accessing your application externally using port 8000? Example `http://mysite:8000/` In most cases you will want to use Nginx or Apache to proxy requests to your container.

Answer (score 1):

I got it!

```
docker run -d -p 80:80/tcp gamehomm/webapplication1
```

Then I changed VM instance details

```
Firewalls
Allow HTTP traffic
Allow HTTPS traffic
```